# Как читать данные из excel файла по номеру столбца python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Задался вопросом: как читать данные из excel файла в питоне с помощью библиотеки pandas. Нашёл решение, что если у столбца есть название, то читать столбец можно, как

```
import pandas as pd
excel = pd.read_excel('./Название файла.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')
names = excel['Название столбца'].tolist()
```

Но если у столбца нет названия? Как читать данные в pandas по номеру столбца?

Comment: по номеру столбца?

Comment: Попробуйте `excel.iloc[:,тут_номер_столбца].tolist()`

Comment: @CrazyElf, Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращение к датафрейму по номерам строк и столбцов производится с помощью метода `iloc`. Чтобы получить все строки определённого столбца нужно будет обратиться так:

```py
names = excel.iloc[:,тут_номер_столбца].tolist()
```